# Conditional option selection from event on angular x

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Select list and I want to launch an action (event) after the user clicks on a choice (Option).

I used (change) event on the Select element, it works but it updated the selected item. there is not an event that can be launched on the click of an option?

The action I want is if the user clicks on an option I do a test if it's true I allow him to select this item,  otherwise he stays on the current.

the current code :

```
<select id="myselect" (change)="verifyData($event.target.value)" formControlName="myElement">
                <option *ngFor="let items of items" [value]="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

## EDITED

You can subscribe to value changes of the form control and set it back to previous value if some logic meets your needs. This should work:

```
ngOnInit(item) {
    this.oldValue = this.form.value.myElement;
    this.form.get('myElement').valueChanges.subscribe((a) => {
    if (a == 3) {
      this.form.get('myElement').setValue(this.oldValue, { emitEvent: false });
    } else {
      this.oldValue = a;
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a link to a working example on stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-conditional-select-change?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: in angular the event click not working in option element, you can test it !! it not works !!

Comment: My mistake, I completely edited the answer and added a working example. Also I suggested a change of the question title. Hope it will help :)

Comment: Thank you, i will try this approch for my use case :)